# CRM Dynamics How to get the current user view url in c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a scenario in CRM where I have a MVC application that connect to CRM and user uploads an excel file with data, that data gets validated against a proc the validated results(records) are then created in CRM using the MVC Application. After the records are created I then send an email to the logged in user's manager ,this email needs to contain a URL/Link to the view where the records have just been created, which is My Active Supplier Claims Update in my instance, How do I query CRM to get the View URL for that logged in user just before I send the email. Please see my code below as to how far I got, I am a bit stuck with this step.

```
public ActionResult ImportDataToCRM(CRM_Embrace_IntegrationEntities1 db)
    {

        int sessionIdentifier = (int)Session["sessionID"];

        var claimsRecords = db.GPClaimsReadyToImports.Where(x => x.CleanSupplierClaimSessionID == sessionIdentifier).ToList();

        CrmConnection conn = new CrmConnection("CRM");
        var service = new OrganizationService(conn);
        OrganizationServiceProxy proxy;// = new OrganizationServiceProxy;
        WhoAmIRequest whoReq = new WhoAmIRequest();
        WhoAmIResponse whoResp = (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(whoReq);
        Guid userid = whoResp.UserId;

        proxy = service.InnerService as OrganizationServiceProxy;
        proxy.CallerId = whoResp.UserId;

        conn.CallerId = userid;

        var cleanClaimsFromDB = claimsRecords; 

        foreach (var claim in cleanClaimsFromDB)
        {
            new_supplierclaimsupdate CRMSupplierClaimsData = new new_supplierclaimsupdate()
            {
                new_Action = claim.Action.Trim(),
                new_InvoiceNumebr = claim.Line_Number.Trim(),
                new_Warning = claim.Warning.Trim(),
                new_TotalClaim = Convert.ToDecimal(claim.Total_Claim).ToString(),
                new_Currency = claim.Currency.Trim(),
                new_Supplier = claim.Claim_Reference.Trim(),
                OwnerId = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, userid),
            };

            Guid _supplierClaimID = service.Create(CRMSupplierClaimsData);

            TempData["supplierClaimID"] = _supplierClaimID;

        }

        Guid supplierClaimsRecordId = Guid.Parse(TempData["supplierClaimID"].ToString());

        Email email = new Email();

        ActivityParty from = new ActivityParty();
        email.OwnerId = from.PartyId = new EntityReference("systemuser", Guid.Parse("B8CB8298-43F4-E211-A707-D067E5EBE694"));

        ActivityParty to = new ActivityParty();
        to.PartyId = new EntityReference("systemuser", Guid.Parse("C4354817-147E-E511-80D4-00155D060AC7")); 


        email.From = new ActivityParty[] { from };
        email.DirectionCode = true;
        email.To = new ActivityParty[] { to };
        email.Subcategory = "Manager To Review Claims Updated  By User";
        email.Description = //The URL VIEW WILL BE ADDED HERE.
        email.RegardingObjectId = new EntityReference("new_supplierclaimsupdate", supplierClaimsRecordId);
        service.Create(email);



        return View("ImportReadyClaims", cleanClaimsFromDB);
    }
```

How can I do this in C# Code. I know of an OOTB way in CRM but that is using an On-Demand workflow and that is not part of the requirement, as this needs to be automated. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a [URL Addressable Forms and Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328483.aspx#BKMK_URLAddressableFormsAndViews).

Assuming your view already exists in CRM then you can follow the instructions in the article above to get the the URL for view.

> 1. Open the view you want to use.
> 2. On the command bar, click Send a Link, and then click Of Current View.
> 3. Paste the link into Notepad and edit it to extract only the URL part of the text that you want.

There are a couple of options, but the URL will look a bit like this:

`http://[CRM Organisation]/main.aspx?etn=[Entity name]&pagetype=entitylist&viewid=%7b[View Id]%7d&viewtype=4230`

- [CRM Organisation] should be populated with your CRM URL, this can be
  accessed using the `CrmConnection` object, i.e. `CrmConnection.ServiceUri`.
- [Entity name] should be populated with your entity name.
- [View Id] should be populated with the Id of your view record in CRM.

You may find my [website](http://bench.woodswork.co.uk/) useful as it contains tools for building URLs and extracting Ids from URLs.